# pandas: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Tags: python, pandas

python 3.7.6 and jupyter notebook

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

chipo = pd.DataFrame(open('orders_24.csv').read().splitlines())

chipo = chipo[0].str.split('\t',expand=True)

chipo.columns = ['order_id', 'quantity', 'item_name', 'choice_description', 'item_price']

chipo = chipo.drop(labels=0)

chipo
```

[This is chipo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sct7W.png)

And I want to find the **item** which has the bigget **roder_id**:

[I tried many ways but can't use this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V97c5.png)

What is wrong with my way?
Or any way to find the biggest **order_id** of that **item**?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me on what line of your code you are running into the TypeError. You should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the dtype of "order_id". It looks like it is an object type. You can verify the dtype with dtypes.

```
print(chipo.dtypes)
```

You cannot find a maximum of an object type. You can change the column type with the astype method and convert the column to an integer type.

```
chipo['order_id'] = chipo['order_id'].astype('int') # Change column type to integer
print(chipo['item_name'].iloc[chipo['order_id'].argmax()]) # Print result
```

Notice if you check the dtypes now, the dtype of `chipo['order_id']` is now an int (integer).

If you don't want to permanently change the column you can implement a single line solution.

```
print(chipo['item_name'].iloc[chipo['order_id'].astype('int').argmax()])
```

Finally, for reference, you should always be aware of the column types you are dealing with. This can save you a lot of troubleshooting down the line.

Comment: thanks!I sloved this problem by changing the dtype.